# Issue using getvalue() to bring in a string from a googlesheet and then parse that string into an array in js

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Thanks for taking the time to look at this - I am sure it's a simple answer. The string in the single cell in the googlesheet is simply:

```
1,Apple,2\n3,Orange,4
```

I'd like to get this value from the googlesheet and then in js convert it to the following array:

```
[ [1, "Apple", 2],[3, "Orange", 4] ]
```

The csv_to_array code below works fine when I provide it with a string in js like this (rather than from the googlesheet using getValue):

```
csv_to_array("1,Apple,2\n3,Orange,4");
```

or if I use:

```
strData = "1,Apple,2\n3,Orange,4";

csv_to_array(strData);
```

Both work.

The csv_to_array code spits out strangeness though when I try to use the string pulled from the googlesheet using getValue() in the following way:

```
var strData = "";

strData = ws.getRange(2, 9, 1, 1).getValue();
```

That gives me an output of:

```
[ [ 1,
    'Apple',
    '2\\n3',
    'Orange',
    4 ] ]
```

I have tried converting this from plain text(?) to a literal string using .String and JSON.Stringify to no effect. I have also tried defining the strData as a string"" or an array [] to see if that worked. It did not.

I have a feeling it's how the \n is being treated but have not been able to crack it. All advice/help greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
const csv_to_array = (data, delimiter = ',', omitFirstRow = false) => {
    data = data.slice(omitFirstRow ? data.indexOf('\n') + 1 : 0)
    let arr = data.split('\n').map(v => v.split(delimiter))
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
            if(!isNaN(arr[i][j])){
                arr[i][j] = parseFloat(arr[i][j])
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, unfortunately, from your showing script, I'm not sure about the script of the value of `That gives me an output of:`, in your situation, how about the following sample scripts?

In the case of the following sample script, it supposes that your value of `1,Apple,2\n3,Orange,4` is put into a cell "A1" of "Sheet1".

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, your script `csv_to_array` is used.

```js
const csv_to_array = (data, delimiter = ',', omitFirstRow = false) => {
    data = "1,Apple,2\n3,Orange,4";
    data = data.slice(omitFirstRow ? data.indexOf('\n') + 1 : 0)
    let arr = data.split('\n').map(v => v.split(delimiter))
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
            if(!isNaN(arr[i][j])){
                arr[i][j] = parseFloat(arr[i][j])
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

// Please run this function.
function main() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const value = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();

  const array = csv_to_array(value);
  console.log(array) // [ [ 1, 'Apple', 2 ], [ 3, 'Orange', 4 ] ]
}
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, as another approach, `Utilities.parseCsv` is used. In this case, as an important point, `\\n` is replaced with `\n`. Because when this replacement is not done,   `[ [ '1', 'Apple', '2\\n3', 'Orange', '4' ] ]` is obtained. I thought that this might be related to your current issue.

```js
function main() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const value = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue().replace(/\\n/g, "\n");

  const array = Utilities.parseCsv(value, ",");
  console.log(array) // [ [ '1', 'Apple', '2' ], [ '3', 'Orange', '4' ] ]
}
```

#### Reference:

- [parseCsv(csv, delimiter)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv,-delimiter)

Comment: Thanks Tanaike - actually the simple '.replace(/\\n/g, "\n")' fixed it, so replacing the plain text of \n with the literal string was the trick. Great!